# Typescript. Function typing

Tags: typescript

Hello I am learning typescript and i follow this exercises: [Link](https://typescript-exercises.github.io/#exercise=14&file=%2Findex.ts)

I have problem understanding how should i proced with this example.

there is a code like this:

```
export function map(mapper, input) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
        return map;
    }
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        return function subFunction(subInput) {
            if (arguments.length === 0) {
                return subFunction;
            }
            return subInput.map(mapper);
        };
    }
    return input.map(mapper);
}
```

and I am supposed to add types to this.
I managed to create something like this:

```
export function map<T>(mapper: Function, input : T[]| any) : T[] | Function {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
        return map;
    }
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        return function subFunction(subInput: T[]|any): T[] | Function {
            if (arguments.length === 0) {
                return subFunction;
            }
            return subInput.map(mapper);
        };
    }
    return input.map(mapper);
}
```

typescript do not returns compilation errors now but i still fail the test. I do not understand what it is expected from me to make this work.

I can check suggested answer but whe i look at it this is dark magic for me.

I could check `test.ts` for what is expected but notation like `const mapResult1 = map()(String)()([1, 2, 3]);` is looking very strange for me.

Comment: That's....a **very** strange function, and certainly not a beginner assignment. It makes me wonder about the quality of the course/exercises.

Comment: The first thing to start `Array.map` function receives a parameter and transforms it into another. So you need at least 2 generic parameters 1 is for arrays element type and 1 is for the output type.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's just some use case of the `map` function:

- When writing `map()` the result is `map` itself
- The next step is `map(String)` which returns `subFunction`
- The next step is `subFunction()` which returns `subFunction` itself
- The last step is `subFunction([1, 2, 3])` which returns the result of the expression `[1, 2, 3].map(String)`: `['1', '2', '3']`

The type of this result is a `string[]` because every element of the final array is the result of `String` being called as a function is always a `string`. Your typings are supposed to resolve this type without even executing the code.

Here is one possible solution found in the source code of the exercises you are doing. They actually revamped the implementation to make it "functional" (return a new function for every unresolved parameter)

```
function toFunctional<T extends Function>(func: T): Function {
    const fullArgCount = func.length;
    function createSubFunction(curriedArgs: unknown[]) {
        return function(this: unknown) {
            const newCurriedArguments = curriedArgs.concat(Array.from(arguments));
            if (newCurriedArguments.length > fullArgCount) {
                throw new Error('Too many arguments');
            }
            if (newCurriedArguments.length === fullArgCount) {
                return func.apply(this, newCurriedArguments);
            }
            return createSubFunction(newCurriedArguments);
        };
    }
    return createSubFunction([]);
}

interface MapperFunc<I, O> {
    (): MapperFunc<I, O>;
    (input: I[]): O[];
}

interface MapFunc {
    (): MapFunc;
    <I, O>(mapper: (item: I) => O): MapperFunc<I, O>;
    <I, O>(mapper: (item: I) => O, input: I[]): O[];
}

/**
 * 2 arguments passed: returns a new array
 * which is a result of input being mapped using
 * the specified mapper.
 *
 * 1 argument passed: returns a function which accepts
 * an input and returns a new array which is a result
 * of input being mapped using original mapper.
 *
 * 0 arguments passed: returns itself.
 */
export const map = toFunctional(<I, O>(fn: (arg: I) => O, input: I[]) => input.map(fn)) as MapFunc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation so the problem is my how this typing should look like?

Comment: I tried to solve your problem but I couldn't without changing the implementation. Indeed, the `if (arguments.length === 0)` lines do not trigger any type guard in TypeScript so according to me you'd have to change these conditions to `if (mapper === undefined)` and `if (subInput === undefined)`

Comment: I actually found the solution here https://github.com/typescript-exercises/typescript-exercises/blob/master/src/exercises/14/index.solution.ts it confirms that the implementation has to be changed. I guess you should adapt the difficulty of the exercises you choose because those are kinda hard!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
interface SubFunction<I, O> {
  (): SubFunction<I, O>;
  (input: I[]): O[];
}

function map<I, O>(): typeof map;
function map<I, O>(mapper: (i: I) => O): SubFunction<I, O>;
function map<I, O>(mapper: (i: I) => O, input: I[]): O[];

function map<I, O>(mapper?: (i: I) => O, input?: I[]) {
  if (mapper && input) {
    return input.map(mapper);
  }
  if (mapper) {
    const subFunction = (input?: I[]) => input ? input.map(mapper) : subFunction;
    return subFunction;
  }
  return map;
}

const mapResult1 = map()(String)()([1, 2, 3]);
```

- It uses a helper type for the SubFunction.
- It uses idiomatic modern TypeScript (no `function` apart from top-level, no `arguments`)
- It uses function overload to have different return types.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcBGAxdIFjAD2IAPAJIA0yA8gHzIDeAsAFDLIAUAlAFxpZc+QiQrV6AbjYdOoAA7ow-cgG0Aun1rqprAL5s2MPAWIhkAWzhyxtOj35gAnnIhEYFqzqPDTH61VtOSzkXKH5ZZW5kAF4GGk0MHGMRMgDJQ2TfYJt6IKtQ8OBImLjqeUVldU0abQNWbxMSPxy7YNCAfkLi2NoykAUwTuRVDSZpZGB3PJDoZAAyOYn+xSiWdg5kKAgwdCgzcrAAOmDp0O4dDn11ya426FXxjgQSAGcwZBfBTKborgOhkZRHoHZDtJYDY5WU73ZD8T5JHwkC4bLY7PYfL6IkDIq4cVG7MzBHRXNjPEBvPwAJQgnwANmAAIwxPw8TioMBQUAAc24rJUDOoACZqABmDQ6IA)